# WinEdt - no bibliography autocompletion pops up with \cite command

Tags: biblatex, winedt

Currently, I have a minor problem working with the *WinEdt* editor: when I enter the `\cite` LaTeX command, no bibliography list pops up.

[image: no pop-up]

Is there anything I need to fix in the preference files like **ActiveStrings.ini** or **AutoComplete.ini**?